# How to edit the last git commit as a patch file?

Tags: git

Sometimes it is useful to modify a commit by editing a [patch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) rather than by changing files directly, adding them to the working set and then amending a commit.

To make this easy, it would be useful to have a command in git that opens the most recent commit in `$EDITOR` *as a patch file*, in the same way that issuing `git commit --amend` (without any changes staged) immediately allows editing of the commit message in an editor.

Is this possible in git

1. as a single command
2. without losing the commit message?

Comment: `git add --edit` does the right thing, but for new changes only

Comment: A possibility: https://blog.aloni.org/posts/gitology-2-git-retext/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible in a single command, but almost:

```
git reset -N HEAD~
git add --edit
git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD
```

some explanations:

- `git reset -N HEAD~` : destroy last commit but keep the changes
- `git add --edit` allows you to edit your changes in *patch* format
- `git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD` : commit your staged changes with the commit message from ORIG_HEAD which is the pointer to the commit you made before `git reset`.

**NOTE:** since only `git add --edit` needs for interaction, you could even just chain the commands on one line and create a bash or git alias for it if desired:

```
git reset -N HEAD~ && git add --edit && git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD
```

---

**NOTE2** if you edit your commit, some changes will remain in your git repository after this command. You must choose to throw them all away (`git checkout -- :/`) or commit them or...

If you don't do anything with these changes; then calling the above commands **twice** will always show you the changes from your very first commit:

```
git commit -am "very first commit"
git reset -N HEAD~
git add --edit # edit very first commit as patch
git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD
# you now have some unstaged changes lying around.
git reset HEAD~ # undo second commit
# the unstaged changes that are lying around now 
# are a combination of second commit and the unstaged changes
# that were still lying around.
# That combination = content of very first commit
git add --edit # edit that combination
git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD
```

If you would like a full command that you can continue applying; you could include the **throwing away of changes:**

```
git reset -N HEAD~ && git add --edit && git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD && git checkout -- :/
```

Note that this is dangerous because you might be throwing away changes...

---

## full-blown script

you might save this script as `/usr/bin/git-edit-last-commit`, then you can run it as `git edit-last-commit`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # exit on first error
if ! git diff-files --quiet
then
    echo "Your git repository is not clean: you have unstaged changes."
    exit 1
fi
if ! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD --
then
    echo "Your git repository is not clean: you have staged changes."
    exit 1
fi
git reset -N HEAD~
git add --edit
git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD
# supposing that this edit is really what you wanted, we can throw away leftovers
# if work was lost, in can be recovered using git reflog
git checkout -- :/
```

Comment: Testing this, it works _once_ but not if _repeated_: make commit, edit-as-patch using command sequence and make change, then run command sequence again and see the patch from the original commit.

Comment: @wodow I have expanded my answer to explain that behavior to you.

Comment: @wodow and now a full-blown script that has some saveguards: you probably don't want to rewrite your list commit and include unstaged/staged changes... otherwise the `git checkout` part at the end could throw away work.

Comment: The `git reset HEAD~` should include `-N`, i.e. `git reset -N HEAD~` so that files that were added in the commit are marked as "intent-to-add" instead of untracked.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need more than one commit edited, you can use `git format-patch` `git am`

```sh
git format-patch ${commit_hash}^ --stdout > patch
# edit the patch file accordingly
git reset --hard ${commit_hash}^
git am < patch
```